# How can I get jQuery to programmatically items in this select list using IE and FF consistently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, jquery-selectors

I have some jQuery code that selects an option in a select list. The first time it selects an item everything works, however the second pass through IE and FF do not clear the selected items.  Chrome always works.

[I have created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7Vyd/4/) with a demo of what I am seeing.  I have tried both `$("testUpdate option:selected")` and `$("testUpdate > option:selected")` as selectors, each work the first time only.  I have tried changing the multiple tag to just multiple [per this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp).

Here is the HTML and relevant failing jQuery.  I have been using jQuery 1.9.1, but on JSFiddle I see the same results with newer versions.

```
//HTML
<select id="testUpdate" name="testUpdateName" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

//jQuery that fails the 2nd pass
$("#testUpdate option:selected").each(function () {
    //This is not executed
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
});

//Alternate selector to force all options to always be checked
//HTML is correct after this, but visually the list is not selected
//I would also prefer not to do this because the actual list will be hundreds of items
$("#testUpdate option").each(function () {
   $(this).removeAttr('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selected` value does not get added to the DOM element, and is therefore not an attribute of the option. You should use `$.prop()`:

```
$("#testUpdate option[value='" + this.getCurrentSelectionValue() + "']").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7Vyd/9/)

Comment: `$.prop()` won't update the actual DOM; it will just change the appearance of the element. If you look at the HTML rendering in any of the debuggers, you won't see that `selected` property on the options. If you want the DOM updated as well, then you'll need to use both `$.attr()` and `$.prop()`.

Comment: Ahh, I see now with this question the difference.  [prop vs attr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)